# distributiono of unlabeled balls in labeled boxes, with a restriction

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

My problem is the following:
Four labelled balls distributed in seven labelled boxes, each of them with a given value: $0,1,2,3,4,5,6$ The number of ways of distributing these balls into the boxes with the restriction of a total value being $6$, gives $84$ states.This means, having one ball in the box labelled $6$ and the other three in the box $0$; or having one in $5$, another in $1$ and the other two in $0$, etc.
However, only $9$ of them produce states which are distinguishable from the point of view of having a different number of balls in the boxes, independent of their labeling. So the question is how to get this value of $9$. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is equivalent to $a+b+c+d=6$

The solutions are: $(6,0,0,0);(5,1,0,0);(4,2,0,0);(4,1,1,0);(3,3,0,0);(3,2,1,0);(3,1,1,1);(2,2,2,0);(2,2,1,1)$

Thus, $9$

If you are looking for a formula, no. There doesn't exist one.(as far as I know)

Answer (score 1):

You are equivalently seeking $$a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{N}$$ such that $$a+b+c+d=6$$
and so immediately we should look to partitions. In particular, we seek the partitions of $6$ which require four or fewer addends.

A brief search in Google, Wikipedia or your favourite sequence database gives a total of eleven partitions of $6$, among which there is one partition using each of five and six addends, excluding them.

The other nine are legitimate for our purposes, and thus there are nine ways to arrange the balls with unique placement in the numbered pots up to relabelling (recolouring, whatever) of the balls.